# Double boot option for Windows showing on my BIOS?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, bios

So I have recently installed Ubuntu (has that caused the following problem, which I will explain?), on my second m.2 drive and it works perfectly fine, but when I go into the boot options in my BIOS so that I can boot into windows when I want to, the boot overrides option menu shows me two identical options which both load into windows perfectly fine, why is it doing that and can I remove one so that only one is shown, it just looks a bit strange.[As you can see from the image it shows two boot override options which are identical and I have tested both, and concluded that they both boot into normal windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sunBN.jpg)

Comment: try disabling CSM and see if this works